# On a quadratic diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, algebraic-surfaces, computational-number-theory

Given a quadratic diophantine equation in $\mathbb Z[x,y,z]$ of form

$$ax^2+by^2+cx+dy+ez+f=0$$ are there standard methods to solve for it when $$\|(x^2,y^2,z)\|_\infty\leq e^{1/2}$$
$$\|(a,b,c,d,e,f)\|_\infty\leq e$$ holds in $O(\mathsf{polylog}(e))$ time?

I noticed we can change the form to shape $X^2+Y^2+ez+g=0$ where $X=a'x+b'$ and $Y=c'y+d'$ for some $a',b',c',d',g\in\mathbb Z$ by completing the square.

So we are asking $$(a'x+b')^2+(c'y+d')^2\equiv-g\bmod e$$ where $$\|(x,y)\|_\infty\leq e^{1/4}$$ holds.

Answer (score 2):

This can be potentially solved by a variation of the [Coppersmith method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith_method), e.g., by that of [Bauer and Joux (2007)](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2007/45150361/45150361.pdf).

Comment: 'Potentially' or provably?

Comment: It's an heuristic method with expected but not provable outcome.

Comment: I think that is for a general trivariate. This is a particular quadratic surface. Arithmetic might help that just combinatorics without arithmetic. Perhaps lot more is known in arithmetic geometry about such surfaces. It is worth going through the arithmetic geometry route.

Comment: Anyway, I did not check carefully and have no ground to say that it's provable.

Comment: Perhaps it is provable for particular surfaces.